# Error when deallocating double pointer in c++

Tags: c++, pointers, double

I am having to build a Cuckoo Hash table. When deallocating my "full" hash tables so that I can resize them and rehash all of my values (from an external file of ints), I get the error:

```
*** glibc detected *** ./a.out: free(): invalid pointer: 0x09c83c7c ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x75002)[0x6b1002]
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6(_ZdlPv+0x18)[0x918fa8]
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6(_ZdaPv+0x18)[0x919008]
./a.out[0x8049678]
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf3)[0x655533]
./a.out[0x8048b11]
```

I am not all that familiar with double pointers but the code was working fine with them untill I tried to deallocate, which I do as follows:

```
for(int j = 0; j < currentSize; j++)
{
    if(HT1[j] != NULL)
    {
        delete [] HT1[j];
    }
    if(HT2[j] != NULL)
    {
        delete [] HT2[j];
    }
}

delete [] HT1;
delete [] HT2;
```

I have a line in the code (`cout.ignore()`) to pause everytime the program rehashes so I can see whats going on every time it does so. Hit enter to continue the code.

Thanks for any help!

```
#include <iostream>//cin and cout
#include <fstream>//file stream
using namespace std;

/***********************************
/Function:
/Arguments:
/Return:
***********************************/
class Value
{
  public:
    Value();
    Value(int newValue);
    ~Value();
    int value;
    bool h1;
    bool h2;
};

/***********************************
/Function:Default constructor for Value class
/Arguments:
/Return:
***********************************/
Value::Value()
{
    value = 0;
    h1 = 0;
    h2 = 0;
}

/***********************************
/Function:Overloaded constructor for Value class
/Arguments:
/Return:
***********************************/
Value::Value(int newValue)
{
    value = newValue;
    h1 = 0;
    h2 = 0;
}

Value::~Value(){};

/***********************************
/Function: Print the hash tables 
/Arguments: Value HT1[]
            Value HT2[]
            int tableSize
/Return:None
***********************************/
void printArrays(Value **table1, Value **table2, int tableSize)
{
    //print out hash table 1 and 2
    cout << "Hash Table 1       Hash Table 2" << endl;
    cout << "------------       ------------" << endl;
    for(int i = 0; i < tableSize; i++)
    {
        cout.width(2);
        cout << right << i << ". ";
        if(table1[i] == NULL)
        {
           std::cout.width(8);
           cout << std::left << '0';
        }
        else
        {
           std::cout.width(8);
           cout << std::left << table1[i]->value;  
        }

        cout << "       ";

        cout.width(2);
        cout << right << i << ". ";

        if(table2[i] == NULL)
        {
            cout << "0" << endl;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << table2[i]->value << endl;
        }

    }

    cout << endl;

}
/***********************************
/Function:
/Arguments:
/Return:
***********************************/
int hash1(int value, int currentSize)
{
    return value % currentSize;
}

/***********************************
/Function:
/Arguments:
/Return:
***********************************/
int hash2(int value, int currentSize)
{
    return (value/currentSize)%currentSize;
}

/***********************************
/Function:Finds the smallest prime number
          greater than 2* tableSize
/Arguments: int tableSize
/Return: prime int
***********************************/
int findPrime(int size)
{
    int rehashSize = (size) * 2 + 1;
    bool prime = 1;



    for(int i = 2; i < rehashSize/2; i++)
    {
        if(rehashSize % i == 0)
        {
            rehashSize++;
            i = 2;
        }
    }

    return rehashSize;

}

int main()
{

    int next;//Stores value from file stream
    int const tableSize = 11;//Size of the hash table
    int currentSize = tableSize;//Stores the current HT size
    int rehashSize;//Holds the size of a rehashed table
    int hash; //Holds the hash value
    int hashTable = 1;//Governor of the switch statement
    Value **HT1 = new Value* [tableSize];//Hash Table 1
    Value **HT2 = new Value* [tableSize];//Hash Table 2
    Value *current;//Stores the value currently being hashed
    Value *temp;//Temporarily holds a Value object if booted from its hash table
    ifstream ifs;//file steam object


    ifs.open("raw_int.txt");//open file stream to file



    while(!(ifs.eof()))
    {

        for(int i = 0; i < currentSize; i++)
        {
            HT1[i] = NULL;
            HT2[i] = NULL;
        }

        printArrays(HT1, HT2, currentSize);

        ifs >> next;  
        current = new Value(next);

        while(!(current->h1 == 1 && current->h2 == 1))
        {   



            cout << "BEFORE - next / hashTable / current / h1 / h2 :: " << next << " " <<  hashTable << " " << current->value  << " " <<
            current->h1 << " " << current->h2 << endl;

            cout << "ARRAY BEFORE" << endl;

            printArrays(HT1, HT2, currentSize);

            switch(hashTable)
            {
                case 1:
                cout << "IN CASE 1\n\n";
                    hash = hash1(current->value, currentSize);
                    cout << "HASH 1: " << hash << endl;
                    if(HT1[hash] == NULL)
                    {
                        HT1[hash] = current;
                        HT1[hash]->h1 = 1;


                        ifs >> next;
                        current = new Value(next);

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        temp = HT1[hash];

                        HT1[hash] = current;
                        HT1[hash]->h1 = 1;

                        current = temp;

                        hashTable = 2;
                    }    
                    break;

                case 2:
                    cout << "IN CASE 2\n\n";

                    hash = hash2(current->value, currentSize);

                    cout << "HASH 2: " << hash << endl;
                    if(HT2[hash] == NULL)
                    {
                        HT2[hash] = current;
                        HT2[hash]->h2 = 1;

                        ifs >> next;
                        current = new Value(next);

                        hashTable = 1;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        temp = HT2[hash];
                        HT2[hash] = current;
                        HT2[hash]->h2 = 1;

                        current = temp;
                        hashTable = 1;
                    }
                    break;
            }

            cout << "AFTER - next / hashTable / current / h1 / h2 :: " << next << " " <<  hashTable << " " << current->value  << " " <<
            current->h1 << " " << current->h2 << endl;
            cout << "ARRAY AFTER: " << endl;
            printArrays(HT1, HT2, currentSize);

        }  

        rehashSize = findPrime(currentSize);

        for(int j = 0; j < currentSize; j++)
        {
            if(HT1[j] != NULL)
            {
                delete [] HT1[j];
            }
            if(HT2[j] != NULL)
            {
                delete [] HT2[j];
            }

        }

        delete [] HT1;
        delete [] HT2;


        currentSize = rehashSize;

        Value **HT1 = new Value* [currentSize];
        Value **HT2 = new Value* [currentSize];



        //printArrays(HT1, HT2, currentSize);

        ifs.seekg(0, ifs.beg);

        cout << "\n\n\n\n\n";
        cout << "---------------------------------------REHASHED:NEW SIZE / CURRENT: " << currentSize << " " << current->value << " ----------------------------------------------" << endl;
        cout << "\n\n\n\n\n";

        cin.ignore();



    }

    printArrays(HT1, HT2, currentSize);



    return 0;
}
```

Comment: A) This is way too much code for a Stack Overflow question. Try to trim it down to a more minimal amount that can reproduce your problem. B) Don't use `new` to allocate arrays. Use `std::vector` or other containers to store that.

Comment: Why are you declaring `HT1` and `HT2` again after the delete?. Not sure what behavior you expect here.

Comment: Anyway, don't bother with Cuckoo hashing. It is nice in theory on the paper, but it kills the performance because of its cache averse behavior (rehashing on collision effectively guarantees cache miss every time). If you want a performant hash table, use array based table with open addressing and local probing (linear, quadratic etc.) ... see e.g. this talk for details https://youtu.be/fHNmRkzxHWs?t=53m15s.

Comment: @axalis Yeah, its for school so I gotsta follow their rules:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think one of the the issues might be in this segment:

```
delete [] HT1;
delete [] HT2;

currentSize = rehashSize;

Value **HT1 = new Value* [currentSize];
Value **HT2 = new Value* [currentSize];
```

You are (always) deleting the HT1 and HT2 allocated at the beginning of `main`, but the `new` then assigns to newly created local variables (but on next iteration the original arrays get deleted again, not the new ones).

Try to remove the `Value **` when doing new (to assign to the existing variables):

```
delete [] HT1;
delete [] HT2;

currentSize = rehashSize;

HT1 = new Value* [currentSize];
HT2 = new Value* [currentSize];
```

which could fix the deletion of the same pointer multiple times.
(and the same also applies for the for loop, where you are again deleting the items multiple times in next iterations)

Also, if you are rehashing, normally you would allocate the new tables before getting rid of the old ones and putting the old items to the new tables first.

---

**EDIT**

When looked closer at the `for` loop, the items should not be deleted by the `delete[]`, because they are allocated via `new`, not via `new[]`, try to change to:

```
for(int j = 0; j < currentSize; j++)
{
    delete HT1[j];
    delete HT2[j];
}
```

(no need to check for `NULL`, because `delete` called on `NULL` pointer skips the deletion automatically)

Comment: @axalix, jodag pointed out that I was redeclaring those variables (out of habit:). I removed the Value**, but I am still getting the same error when attempting to deallocate.  As far a rehashing to new tables, I'm doing the whole process in a loop so I wanted to keep the hash table variable names the same.

Comment: Updated - in the for loop, you should call `delete`, not `delete[]`.

Comment: @alalis Bingo. Thank you very much!